# Pass a variable from Powershell to saved SQL Script

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell

I have a Powershell Function that is being used to run multiple queries in SQL and export as CSVs. Each of these queries relies on a date variable. Is there a way to pass this date variable from Powershell into these SQL Scripts (not stored procedures) using my current setup? Any help is much appreciated!

```
Function Run-Query
{
    param([string[]]$queries,[string[]]$sheetnames)
    Begin
    {

        $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $Database; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
        Write-host "Connection to database successful."
    }#End Begin
    Process
    {
        # Loop through each query
        For($i = 0; $i -lt $queries.count; $i++)
        {
            $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

            # Use the current index ($i) to get the query
            $SqlCmd.CommandText = $queries[$i]

            $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
            $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
            $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
            $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
            $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

            # Use the current index ($i) to get the sheetname for the CSV
            $DataSet.Tables[0] #| Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\Users\mbaron\Downloads\$($sheetnames[$i]).csv"
        }
    }#End Process
    End
    {
        $SqlConnection.Close()
    }
}#End function run-query.
```

Comment: Where are you queries coming from? This function does not generate or edit queries?

Comment: Read up on parameterized queries with ADO.NET

Comment: @Matt i pull the queries from files on my computer
$SqlQuery1 = get-content "C:\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\test\test.sql" | Out-String;
$queries = @()
$queries += @"
$SqlQuery1
"@

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could add a marker in your queries where the data is being used, then do a replace with the relevant date, e.g.:

```
cls
$date = '1/1/2016'
$query = 'some $$marker$$ script'
$query = $query.replace('$$marker$$', $date )
$query
```

Comment: That is how you get SQL Injection.

Comment: Remus, all code is under control of this user, no sql injection can occur unless it is communicating with external users.

Comment: @Jimbo SQL injection can come from *any* malformed input - the user could easily fat-finger as they type. Always assume that any input can carry a malicious or otherwise invalid payload (intentional or not) and use proper practices to protect against it.

Comment: alroc - the function already accepts sql as a parameter, are you telling me that sql accepted as a parameter is ok but within the function it is not ok to change that sql?  very strange idea!

Comment: @Jimbo I ended up outputting the file contents as a string and then replacing the value of my variable with what I need in the string. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @mtb2434 Great!  Can you mark the answer then please?